# Ionic - openFileDialog does not work correctly (does not start or crash)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have some trouble with ionic. On android less then 4.4.2 openFileDialog not worked. On device with android 4.4.2-6.x openFileDialog is working. Application crashed when user selected image on 4.4.2. On android 6.x application crash only user select image via gallery.

View

```
<ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="stampImage in orderSettings.getStampImages() ">
              <a class="item item-thumbnail-left">
                <img  file-preview="stampImage" />
                <h2> {{ stampImage.name }}</h2>
              </a>
            </ion-item>

          </ion-list>

          <button id="getRStampFile" style="text-align:right;" class="button button-positive  icon-left ion-android-add-circle" ng-click="openFileDialog()">Add image</button>
          <input type="file" id="fileRStamp" ng-model="newImage" base-sixty-four-input file-changed hidden />
```

Controller

```
$scope.openFileDialog=function() {
    console.log('fire! $scope.openFileDialog()');
    ionic.trigger('click', { target: document.getElementById('fileRStamp') });
  };
```

Direcive

```
.directive('fileChanged', function (orderSettings) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) {
        return;
      }

      ngModel.$render = angular.noop;

      element.bind('change', function (event) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.files[0]);
        if (event.target.files[0].name.localeCompare('')!=0){
          orderSettings.addStampImages(event.target.files[0]);
          var file = event.target.files[0];
          var reader  = new FileReader();
          reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            //preview.src = reader.result;
            orderSettings.addStampImages64({'filename': file['name'], 'filebody': reader.result});
          }, false);

          if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
        }
        $scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
})
```

When I'm testing in browser - all working fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use the plug of the camera to access the gallery?

Comment: I need only select image from storage in this application.